# GCP cloudbuild doesn't trigger pipline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to setup the GCP `cloudbuild pipeline` for my `bitbucket` repo. However, it's not being triggered.

I am using following sample from their own website.

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      echo "Hello, world!" > /persistent_volume/file
  volumes:
  - name: 'myvolume'
    path: '/persistent_volume'
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      cat /persistent_volume/file
  volumes:
  - name: 'myvolume'
    path: '/persistent_volume'
```

I have following action enabled for webhook
[image]

even if if I keep this simple singe step it's not working.

```yaml
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      echo "Hello, world!"
```

**Error**
If I keep in trigger in `global` region it complain about `vpc-sc` error

```
RESOURCES_NOT_IN_SAME_SERVICE_PERIMETER
```

if I move the pipeline to `northamerical-northeast1` it says

```
triggerError spanner trigger (923134934784, test) not found
```

Comment: There are many things to check. First, are you performing a pull request to validate your trigger? Then, what the URL endpoint of the  WebHook? Did you create it manually or was it created by Cloud Build itself? If manually, did you correctly add the API Key in the webhook URL?

Comment: I think I found out the issue, If I keep in trigger in `global` region it complain about `vpc-sc` error `that RESOURCES_NOT_IN_SAME_SERVICE_PERIMETER` if I move the pipeline to `northamerical-northeast1` it says `triggerError spanner trigger (923134934784, test) not found`

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to replicate your issue by following this link on [creating webhook triggers](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automate-builds-webhook-events#creating_webhook_triggers) and got the same error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "triggerError spanner trigger (${PROJECT_ID}, ${TRIGGER_NAME}) not found",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

The weird thing is even if I selected a non-global region, the webhook URL preview generated is for a global region.

Upon doing some research online, there's an ongoing issue when creating regional webhooks. You can check the status through this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/242590206).

You can track the link above for updates.